# Robotframework : file_1.robot needs to update a variable in file_2.robot

Tags: robotframework

I tried using the Set Global Variable keyword but I am not sure if I am doing this correct. I was hoping to make 2 files have access to this variable. Here is my variables section. I am using VS code with Robot plugin for syntax highlighting. The error show when I run this
is:

*Invalid variable name 'Set Global Variable'.robotcode.diagnostics(ModelError)*

```
*** Variables ***

Set Global Variable    ${VERBOSE}    0

${SERIAL_PORT}    None
```

Is there a special library I need to import to use Set Global Variable?

My use case is that I have 2 robot files both of them need to know if Verbose mode is enabled. I pass verbose to **file_1.robot** file via command line, I was hoping I could also pass the verbose variable to a Resource **file_2.robot**, but I am unable to do this because
in my second file there is no "command line argument to pass in to it"

Is there a way from  **file_1.robot** I can set/update a variable in **file_2.robot** ?

For file one i can do this via command line, but for file 2 I was hoping something like this would exist:

```
Resource     ../resources/Serial.robot -v Verbose:0
```

(in this case Serial.robot is the infamous file 2 )

To make things even simpler I dont need Verbose in File 1 , i Just need it to pass it on to the resource file somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set Global Variable` is a keyword that could be used inside test cases or custom keywords. What you need is to define variable ([link to documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-section)).

> I pass verbose to file_1.robot file via command line, I was hoping I could also pass the verbose variable to a Resource file_2.robot, but I am unable to do this because in my second file there is no "command line argument to pass in to it"

Nope, you are passing global variable visible from everywhere. Take a look at [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-priorities-and-scopes) about scopes and priorities for variables.

If you want to define once and use in multiple places you could create file with common variables and import in both files. Example:

Here you define:

```
# BaseVariables.robot
*** Variables ***
${VERBOSE}    0
```

And use:

```
# file_1.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource    BaseVariables.robot
```

and in second file

```
# file_2.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource    BaseVariables.robot
```